# Си, Си++, Нарушение доступа для записи

Tags: c++, c, массивы, функции, динамические-массивы

```cpp
void separateAndPrint(char* string, int start)
{
    int i = start;
    int count = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0' && string[i] != ' ')
    {
        count++;
        i++;
    }

    //Выделяем память под слово
    char* word = (char)malloc(100);

    if (word != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; string[start] != ' ' && string[start] != '\0'; i++, start++)
        {
            word[i] = string[start]; //тут ошибка[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
        }

        word[i + 1] = '\0';

        for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", word[i]);
        }
    }

    return word;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обратите внимание на строку, где выделяете память: Вы кастуете к типу `(char)`, в то время как надо `(char*)malloc(100)`. Значение указателя `word` невалидное, хотя и `malloc` сработал, и проверку `word != NULL` прошло. Смотрите пример  [здесь](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7fbWbhPW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* word = (char)malloc(100);
```

Здесь происходит урезание 32 или 64 бит указателя до 8 бит `char`. ВероятноЮ вы хотели написать

```
char* word = (char*)malloc(100);
```

Но если у вас С, то вообще никакое приведение не надо — вполне сработает

```
char* word = malloc(100);
```

Приведение требуется только в С++.